# How to test create model service?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, model, mocking

I decided to create CreateClassroomService to separte logic in my controller method.

```
class CreateClassroomService extends Service
{
    public function create(string $name, User $user): ?Classroom
    {
        $this->checkName($name);

        $classroom = new Classroom();
        $created = $classroom->setName($name)
            ->associateUser($user)
            ->save();

        return $created ? $classroom : null;
    }

    private function checkName(string $name): void
    {
        if (empty($name)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this service as part of learning unit testing, but I don't know how. I don't know how to mock the classroom object to control what the method should return. Does this mean that creating this service was not a good idea because I am not able to test it? Should I build this service differently? Unless the service can be tested, but I don't know how... What should I check in assertion?

This is my test but it is not good because I am not able to force what should be returned.

```
public function testGivenCreateCorrectDataClassroomWillBeCreated(): void
    {

        $name = 'Test classroom';
        $user = Mockery::mock(User::class);


        $result = $this->service->create($name, $user);

        $this->assertTrue($result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how mocking works in Mockery, but lets review what you are doing: your create function that you are trying to test creates a new instance of a `Classroom`, and since it instantiates the object inline you have no control over it.

From the code you have written, I am assuming that you build a classroom object and return, never using the same creator instance again, so what you can do is add a constructor to `CreateClassroomService` through which you **inject** a `Classroom` object. If you are using the same create service to create multiple classroom objects at a time, you will also need to make sure that you somehow reset the classroom instance to its default state inbetween creation(s), or you inject a fresh & new classroom object before invoking `create` again. This wholly depends on what the classroom does though.

The classroom object then can be mocked through unit testing -- you inject the mock instance and youre good to go. You actually are already injecting `User` object, so you're already on the right lines!

```
class CreateClassroomService extends Service {

private ?Classroom $classroom;

public function __construct(Classroom $classroom) {
    $this->classroom = $classroom;
}

...
}
```

Now you just need to mock your classroom object in your test, inject the mock into your service when instantiating the object, and off you go. :)

Btw I would also say you may want to consider do some more abstraction on your service in the form of interfaces or review your parent class to make it more unit testable in general. Generally speaking for effective unit testing you want to avoid static methods and `new` keywords; where you can absolutely not avoid it, one approach might be to wrap just that one line of code in an encapsulated method, so you can mock the method instead to return you mock data / mock instances instead (but generally if you have to do this it should be an obvious sign to alert you to having sub-par architecture).

Comment: thanks @peterxz, it's a very simple way and I didn't think about such an undertaking

Comment: Whoever reads this solution, never _mock_ a model, you have to use [`factories`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) and assertions to make sure you are creating, updating, deleting, interacting with your desired model... Check my profile and see my answers related to Unit testing... you will find a lot of information in my answers about this topic...

Comment: I think you are confusing the tests. In this test, I want to check the operation of the service, not saving in the database

Comment: @matiaslauriti If he was testing the model itself, I absolutely agree with you -- do not use what I outlined above, there are better ways. However, if you are just testing any service / object, mocked object via dependency injection is the way to go. :)

Comment: @longmaikel I get your point, but still, if you have a model as an operation to test, you still do not mock that, you use factories and assert that on the DB, it is not expensive nor complex. It is how it is tested on Laravel to make it easier, there could be a lot of stuff going behind scenes, like an event being triggered that could potentially change data before it is saved, and you are going to miss that if you don't account for that data being what you expected to be, hence making sure your model's `save` method was run... truste me, I have 5 years experience on this, do it the other way.

Comment: I also understand your point. Don't convince me with years of experience because I know people who work longer than me and have little idea about the things they do. Convince me with arugments that show the advantage of your way

Comment: Using your method, please show me how to check the service behavior when saving to the database is unsuccessful. Your solution only tests a positive use case.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, you could simply assert that the ClassRoom has in fact been created. Docs

As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test), update your test class so that it's using the `RefreshDatabase` trait e.g.:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase 
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
```

Laravel has [Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) to make creating models with dummy data very quick and easy. There should already be a `UserFactory` created for you (you may need to update it if you've updated the default users migration).

```
public function testGivenCreateCorrectDataClassroomWillBeCreated(): void
{   
    $name = 'Test classroom';
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $result = $this->service->create($name, $user);

    $this->assertInstanceOf(ClassRoom::class, $result);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('class_rooms', ['name' => $name]);
}
```

Don't forget to import the `User` and `ClassRoom` models in to your test class.

Comment: As @Rwd mentioned, you never mock `models` on Laravel, you use [`factories`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) and assert the model exists with your expected data...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Why should I use the database in a unit test? The unit test should be isolated and test a small part of the code in this case, the service logic. I will check whether the model is saved in the database in the integration test of the **create** method in the controller.
I consider this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237450/how-to-test-create-model-service/70237525#70237525) is much better. Just inject the model into the constructor then I will be able to use the mock to simulate the behavior

Comment: @longmaikel no sir, again, if you are using `models`, you are interacting with the database or whatever connection you are using... The database should be a "test" database, create a new one and use that only for tests, using `RefreshDatabase` trait will auto truncate it and auto migrate it... The answer marked as a solution it is NOT good practice...

Comment: As I mentioned I don't have much experience when it comes to writing tests. Most of the sources I read recommended not to use the database for unit tests. I would like to hear the opinions of other people about the suitability of your solution. You may be right and I should do as you suggest. But I'm not convinced of this solution.

Comment: As I mentioned, I think that the purpose of the test written for the website described in the question is to check whether the setter with the correct data was used and whether the save method was called. With mocks, I have the option to simulate a situation in which the data has been saved correctly in the database or not. With your solution, I do not have such an option and the test depends on third-party resources (in this case, the database).

Comment: As I mentioned, I am going to write an integration test for endpoint `/classroom/create` where I will check, if the record has been saved in the database. I hope to hear what other users think about the proposed considerations. if your way is correct I will write the test in the way you suggested

Comment: @longmaikel I was just giving you one way to do it. Yes, in a purest way, you wouldn't hit the DB with a Unit test, however, I wouldn't consider the approach I gave you a strict unit test. Ultimately, testing the outcome is pretty much all you want i.e. you're not limiting yourself to a strict implementation.

Comment: Okay I understand your approach.